# How to pull files from github branch to xcode directly?

Tags: xcode, github, git-pull

I have a project created for me by teacher and I have to improve it. He created a repo on Git Hub with branch for me. I'm trying to pull the project files from that branch directly to Xcode and Xcode refers to the branches that I have created which are empty, not the master one. Can't find any adequate manual for that as well... Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so github uses `git` to manage repositories, so this question has more to do with git than with github.

Git is a distributed-repository source-control system, which means that every machine has a full copy of the repository, with all of its history and branches. This means that your local repository that you cloned from GitHub has all of the branches on it.

So, your problem is actually just that you need to switch branches locally to the branch your professor created.

In a terminal you can execute

```
git checkout <the-name-of-the-branch-your-teacher-created>
```

and that should do it. :)

Xcode is simply looking at the files in your `working directory`, so switching branches will update the files in Xcode as well.

For more git information check out [the git book](http://git-scm.com/book) or any of the other countless git resources online!

Comment: to clarify, when you pulled the project, you pulled ALL the branches, you just have to switch to the right one in your local working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Well using Git is fairly simple and as specified above can pull the project (either complete of specific brach and then import it. 
**OR**

While running Xcode you can follow below steps -

1. Click on Check out an existing project.

[image]

2. Enter Repo link as shown below and hit Next.

[image]

3. Select the branch that you want to pull and hit Next.

[image]

**Note** As shown in Image Xcode version 8.2.1 is used.